# select multiple products from selectbox and enter quantity for each selected product

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

it is the simple POS system for one product.But now i have to extend for multiple products.it works like when i select multiple product it shows a separate box where the selected product name is written and in parallel there is an input box of quantity.is it possible through jquery or in php?it would be a great help if someone helps me to sort out

```
     <form method="POST" style="width:60%;margin-left:200px">
     <div class="form-group">
       <label>Choose Product:</label>
          <select name="product_id" class="form-control" class="select" id="select_items" multiple > 
             <option disabled selected>-- Select Product --</option>
             <!-- to retrive data from database and show into dropdown  -->
             <?php
                 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login');
                 $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * From products where deleted=0");  // Use select query here 
                 while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
                 {
                 echo "<option value=". $data['id'] ." >" .$data['name'] ."    </option>";  // displaying data in option menu
                 }  
             ?>  
          </select>
                <label> Quantity: </label>
                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control"  ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required=""  />  
                </div> 
                <button class="btn" name="submit-product" type="submit" ID="btnClick"  >Submit</button> 
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using jQuery.

We have to have a wrapper for quantity selection area using id, just need to have a onchange event listener to selection.

When we change selection, jQuery function calls, within that jQuery function, we have to gather the all options selected and then using for loop, we can clone the quantity wrapper content and change the content.

For example:

```
function populate() {
  $('#select_items :selected').each(function() {
    let html = '';
    html += '<div>';
    html +='<label> Quantity:'+$(this).text()+' </label>';
    html += '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" ID="txtName" placeholder="Enter Quantity" required="" val='+$(this).val()+' />';
    html += '</div>'
   
    $('#selected-quantity').append(html)
  })
}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" style="width:60%;margin-left:200px">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose Product:</label>
    <select name="product_id" class="form-control" class="select" id="select_items" multiple onchange="populate()">
      <option disabled selected>-- Select Product --</option>
      <option value="foo1">foo1</option>
      <option value="foo2">foo2</option>
      <option value="foo3">foo3</option>
      <option value="foo4">foo4</option>
      <option value="foo5">foo5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="selected-quantity">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <form>
```

Comment: thanks for the help,its working fine.is there any need to change the query for the insertion of multiple products?                                                                                                            $sql="INSERT INTO sales SET product_id='$product_id', product_qty='$quantity', datetime='$date',total_amount='$totalAmount' ";

Comment: yes. When inserting , you have to use the foreach loop to loop the passing quantity array     foreach($products as $key=>$val){ $sql ="insert into sales SET product_id='$val' ,product_qty='$quantity[$key]'"}

Comment: on the basis of multi selection of products,there is also need to change the quantity of productstock which is linked through the sale table then what changing will be made for this? if(isset($_POST['submit-product']))  {   
              if($qtyByUser <= $fetchedQty) {
                    $finalQty = $fetchedQty-$qtyByUser;
                    $querryToDeductRecord ="UPDATE `productstock` SET `quantity` = $finalQty WHERE `productstock`.`product_id` = $product_id";
                    $querryToDeductRecord=mysqli_query($db,$querryToDeductRecord);  }

Comment: Yes you can deduct the product stock using your query

Comment: for multiple products there is need to change the update query or query remain same?